# Extend Vue function in component to display ID

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Vue component and I am using `internalValue` to access the value attribute. How would I extend this to also get the `ID`?

ie internalValue = `value, id`

I have tried but I don't know how to add this inside the internalValue function. I've even tried to only get the ID by changing all instances of value to id but it still spits out the value.

I'd be happy to have them as one ie `value, id` or access them like `data.value` and `data.id`

**Initialise Vue**

```
new Vue({
        el: '#topic',
        data: {
        selectedTopic: null
    }
});
```

**Use Component**

```
<div class="form-group" id="topic">
    <topic v-model="selectedTopic"></topic>
</div>
```

**Register Component**

```
Vue.component('topic', require('./components/Topicselect.vue'));
```

**Component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label v-for="topic in topics" class="radio-inline radio-thumbnail">
      <input type="radio" v-model="internalValue" name="topics_radio" :id="topic.id" :value="topic.name">
      <span class="white-color lg-text font-regular text-center text-capitalize">{{ topic.name }}</span>
    </label>
    <ul class="hidden">
      <li>{{ internalValue }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['value'],
  data () {
    return {
      internalValue: this.value,
      topics: []
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    axios.get('/vuetopics').then(response => this.topics = response.data);
  },
  watch: {
    internalValue(v){
      this.$emit('input', v);
      console.log('Topicselect: the value is ' + this.internalValue);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the selected topic as your value. Basically, eliminate `internalValue` altogether, and just emit the topic associated with any given radio button when it's clicked. This will satisfy `v-model`, since it listens to `input` events (unless you customize it).

```
export default {
  props: ['value'],
  data () {
    return {
      topics: []
    }
  },
  methods:{
    selectValue(topic){
      this.$emit('input', topic)
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    axios.get('/vuetopics').then(response => this.topics = response.data);
  }
})
```

And your template

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label v-for="topic in topics" class="radio-inline radio-thumbnail">
      <input type="radio" @click="selectValue(topic)" name="topics_radio" :id="topic.id" :value="topic.name" :checked="value && topic.id == value.id">
      <span class="white-color lg-text font-regular text-center text-capitalize">{{ topic.name }}</span>
    </label>
    <ul class="hidden">
      <li>{{ value }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

This will set `selectedTopic` in your Vue to a topic, which is something like

```
{
    id: 2,
    name: "some topic"
}
```

based on how you use it in your template.

[Working example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/JWrMGW?editors=1010).

Comment: @ClintonGreen You're welcome :)  I edited in a change to the template later, specifically `:checked="value && topic.id == value.id"`, in case at some point you started with a value instead of null.

Comment: Yeah first 2 times I got the id = null error but I saw the edits. Thanks heaps.